# Undefined reference to an external function

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm trying to compile some code on Eclipse (The code compiles fine with Visual Studio). I'm getting an undefined reference error for functions that are defined as external.

In Project->Properties->C++ Settings->Compiler->Includes I have set the Folder where files A and B (See below) are located.
I also added file A to Project->Properties->Settings->Linker->Miscellaneous.

File A:

```
//Function prototype
void MyFunc();

//Function implementation
void MyFunc()
{
//Some Implementation
}
```

File B:

```
//Declare extern function
extern void MyFunc();


//usage of extern function
//This would generate the undefined reference error
MyFunc();
```

Comment: Are both source files part of the project? Are both source files built into object files, and are both object files linked into the executable program? If you read the build-log, what does it say?

Comment: Instead of having a really weird project structure, put the prototype in A.h, the definition in A.c and from B.c `#include "A.h"`. There is absolutely no reason why you would do it any other way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm a bit lost as Eclipse is new to me. Both files are in the same project. The build log says "undefined reference to MyFunc". In the Debug folder I have *.O files, i'm guessing these are the object file? Not sure how to make sure the object files are linked to the executable program, can you please guide me?

Comment: @Lundin You're probably right, but as I inherited this code, this is how it is implemented. Anyways, as I said, this code works with Visual Studio so I guess either I'm doing something wrong with Eclipse or I'm missing something.

Comment: please show the exact project structure, the exact filenames and the exact compiler/linker output